# Starting off with vim

Tags: vim

I have just started off with vim today and can't really configure it properly. I can't configure to look as shown in the screenshots while downloading
I am using

```
        VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Apr  2 2013 09:18:16)
        Included patches: 1-547
```

Can anyone please help me configuring it

Comment: No, we won't hold your hand during the whole process, that's not how this site works and that's not what you need. If you have seen fancy screenshots, ask their authors how they did it but you are starting from the wrong end: when you start with Vim, you have quite a lot of learning to do before getting into the configuration rabbit hole. Start by going through `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed to feel at least a little comfortable, then type `:help`, follow along and come back with real, focused, questions. If you wanted to get up to speed quickly, you bet on the wrong horse.

Comment: This question is extremely broad. Can you narrow it down a bit to be more specific? There are tons of configuration-scripts out there. Start by googling "configure vim" and take it from there, then come back here with a more specific question. Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure anything; Vim comes with all the good stuff included.

However, creating a personal configuration (as evidenced by the multitude of blog posts, tutorials, etc. on the web) can become a lifelong quest for some (and it's worthwhile to invest in an optimal editing environment!)

For starters, learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.